# When do I need to worry about size_type?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, size-type

I've read that using `std::vector<T>::size_type` is more portable than `std::size_t`, although `size_type` is usually `std::size_t`. For example it's more recommended to do this:

```
for (typename std::vector<T>::size_type i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << vec[i] << " ";
```

than this:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << vec[i] << " ";
```

That seems like a lot of typing though. You can't use `auto` because the initializer will be deduced to int. A type alias is useless because you might as well type it out when you use it. There aren't many cases where that would actually save typing.

I tried to do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct size_type
{
    using type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;
};
```

But it just ends up being `typename size_type<T>::type` which is just as much typing.

By far, `std::size_t` is the shortest thing to type. When do you actually need to worry about `size_type`?

Comment: Why not use `for (auto const & x : vec) std::cout << x << " ";` and stop worrying about iteration-internal parameters?

Comment: @KerrekSB A ranged-based for is not as flexible.

Comment: `for (auto e = v.size(), i = decltype(e){}; i != e; ++i)`... [ugh](http://ideone.com/DMU0PM).

Comment: @user4340517 You might as well use iterators and `for(auto it = std::begin(vec); it != std::end(vec); ++it)`. Problem solved!

Comment: Would `template<class T> using size_type = typename vector<T>::size_type;` help?